# Wampserver cakephp 1.3 Strict standards error

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling, wamp

I'm currently growing crazy over my new Wampserver at the moment. I switched to a new computer and installed Wamp and moved my cakephp 1.3 folder to the `C:\wamp\www` folder, and all I get is this error:

[image: my error message]

Here's some facts I'm aware of and stuff I'm already tried:

- This is an existing project, and I can't just go to CakePHP 2 since it may break the code
- I have edited the `error_reporting` in the **correct** `php.ini` file. I've tried everything regarding `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`
- When changing the `php.ini` file, I have done everything from restart my windows to restarting the Wampserver

Does anyone know what I'm missing? It's frustrating to go through 20 guides and answers whom should solve the problem but doesn't.

The errors still exists, and the rest of the site works as intended.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest 1.3 stable release (1.3.15), it already sets `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);` internally.

Edit: Just to clarify further you must be using an older 1.3 release which sets `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` in the core thereby overriding the reporting level you set in your php.ini

Comment: Hmm that's a good point. I ended up downloading the same version as my servers were running on, so it went well anyways. Thanks for the help, and it would most likely been the reply I wanted.

Comment: Small note, the error_reporting must be set after the Configure::write to work.

Comment: i was going crazy the last 2 hours searching this... i hate that the the company im working for right now still uses cake 1.2. and cannot upgrade... Unbelievable? right... still true :/